# AngularJS function not triggered via ngf-select

Tags: angularjs, file, upload

Trying to upload an image file and process it in an AngularJS function called onFileSelect. However after the Choose File button was clicked the value of $scope.fileMsg inside onFileSelect was not updated. Any tips? Thanks a bunch!

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form name="myForm">
        <div>
            <input type="file" ngf-select="onFileSelect(file)" name="file">
            <span ng-show="fileMsg">{{fileMsg}}</span>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script>
   var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
   app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.fileMsg = "Checkpoint 1";
        $scope.onFileSelect = function(file) {
        $scope.fileMsg = "Checkpoint 2";
        }
    }
);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to insert the 'ngFileUpload' in the module, like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngFileUpload']);
```

And, if you haven't already, inject the necessary scritps.

Here is a working Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/23032/

Comment: Thanks! I was able to make it after adding the ngFileUpload. I also needed to download a copy of ng-file-upload.js and include it in the HTML. Cheers :-)